# VSTO Word post save event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, vsto

Sorry for the length of this, In the past I've been asked before to included everything I've tried when asking these sort of questions.

I'm writing a Word Add-in and need to make changes to the document that I cannot achieve using the Word object model. Therefore, after the document is save to disk, I need to capture that event, close the file, do what I need to do and reopen it. (I know, not elegant, but that's what I have to work with.)

Word has Before Save and Before Close, but no after save event. I found tricks online to simulate an after save event by creating another thread and using COM's [IMessageFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693740(v=vs.85).aspx) (not from System.Windows.Forms) to handle COM Retry calls, or posting a message back on the main thread so I can execute code after it's saved. But this doesn't work because if the file is saved as a result of the user attempting to close the document I can't get the file name in my "callback" method because Word.Document object has already been deleted.

So I tried explicitly call Save myself in my BeforeSave event handler and return Cancel = true. That works great when user selects save, or they had once saved to disk. But if the user closes a new document without saving and then selects 'yes' to whether or not they want to save, Word displays another "SaveAs" dialog after I've already handled the save after I return from the BeforeSave event, even though I set Cancel = true in my BeforeSave event handler.

So then I tried doing the something similar with the BeforeClose event. I handle the close and save myself and then returning Cancel = true from my event handler. But doing so stops word from trying to close multiple documents when the user is attempting to shut down the application.

I even tried handling WM_CLOSE, but that lead to similar problems as above.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 7):

I came across [this](https://davecra.com/2013/04/26/updated-word-after-save-event/) a while back, I think it may do what you want. Here's a copy of what's there  in case it ever disappears.

---

When I wrote my first [Word AfterSave Event](https://davecra.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/word-aftersave-event) entry, it was designed for Word 2007, and was – as it turns out – not a catch all. So I have updated it here (thanks for the catch go to Pat Lemm).

When the document was closed, you never got access to the Saved filename. So, I have updated the code here and it now works in all conditions and has been tested in Word 2013.

Here is how it works:

1. Upon initialization you pass it your Word object.
2. It attaches to the Before Save Event.
3. When any save event occurs, it kicks off a thread that loops until the Background Save is complete.
4. Once the background save is done, it checks to see if the document Saved == true:

   - If Saved == true: then a regular save did occur.
   - If Saved == false: then it had to be an AutoSave

In each case it will fire a unique event:

- AfterSaveUiEvent
- AfterSaveEvent
- AfterAutoSaveEvent

Additionally, if the document being saved is also being closed, we catch the filename on the WindowDeactivate event on the way out. This can now be accessed by the caller (as you can see in the example below), to get the full filename of the closed document.

Here is the code to the class:

```
public class WordSaveHandler
{
    public delegate void AfterSaveDelegate(Word.Document doc, bool isClosed);
    // public events
    public event AfterSaveDelegate AfterUiSaveEvent;
    public event AfterSaveDelegate AfterAutoSaveEvent;
    public event AfterSaveDelegate AfterSaveEvent;
    // module level
    private bool preserveBackgroundSave;
    private Word.Application oWord;
    string closedFilename = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// CONSTRUCTOR  takes the Word application object to link to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oApp"></param>
    public WordSaveHandler(Word.Application oApp)
    {
        oWord = oApp;
        // hook to before save
        oWord.DocumentBeforeSave += oWord_DocumentBeforeSave;
        oWord.WindowDeactivate += oWord_WindowDeactivate;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Public property to get the name of the file
    /// that was closed and saved
    /// </summary>
    public string ClosedFilename
    {
        get
        {
            return closedFilename;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// WORD EVENT  fires before a save event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Doc"></param>
    /// <param name="SaveAsUI"></param>
    /// <param name="Cancel"></param>
    void oWord_DocumentBeforeSave(Word.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        // This could mean one of four things:
        // 1) we have the user clicking the save button
        // 2) Another add-in or process firing a resular Document.Save()
        // 3) A Save As from the user so the dialog came up
        // 4) Or an Auto-Save event
        // so, we will start off by first:
        // 1) Grabbing the current background save flag. We want to force
        //    the save into the background so that Word will behave 
        //    asyncronously. Typically, this feature is on by default, 
        //    but we do not want to make any assumptions or this code 
        //    will fail.
        // 2) Next, we fire off a thread that will keep checking the
        //    BackgroundSaveStatus of Word. And when that flag is OFF
        //    no know we are AFTER the save event
        preserveBackgroundSave = oWord.Options.BackgroundSave;
        oWord.Options.BackgroundSave = true;
        // kick off a thread and pass in the document object
        bool UiSave = SaveAsUI; // have to do this because the bool from Word
        // is passed to us as ByRef
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Handle_WaitForAfterSave(Doc, UiSave);
        }).Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is the thread call that waits for the same to compelte. 
    /// The way we detect the After Save event is to essentially enter into
    /// a loop where we keep checking the background save status. If the
    /// status changes we know the save is compelte and we finish up by
    /// determineing which type of save it was:
    /// 1) UI
    /// 2) Regular
    /// 3) AutoSave
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Doc"></param>
    /// <param name="UiSave"></param>
    private void Handle_WaitForAfterSave(Word.Document Doc, bool UiSave)
    {
        try
        {
            // we have a UI save, so we need to get stuck
            // here until the user gets rid of the SaveAs dialog
            if (UiSave)
            {
                while (isBusy())
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

            // check to see if still saving in the background
            // we will hang here until this changes.
            while (oWord.BackgroundSavingStatus > 0)
                Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // we will get a thread abort exception when Word
            // is in the process of closing, so we will
            // check to see if we were in a UI situation
            // or not
            if (UiSave)
            {
                AfterUiSaveEvent(null, true);
            }
            else
            {
                AfterSaveEvent(null, true);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            oWord.Options.BackgroundSave = preserveBackgroundSave;
            return; // swallow the exception
        }

        try
        {
            // if it is a UI save, the Save As dialog was shown
            // so we fire the after ui save event
            if (UiSave)
            {
                // we need to check to see if the document is
                // saved, because of the user clicked cancel
                // we do not want to fire this event
                try
                {
                    if (Doc.Saved == true)
                    {
                        AfterUiSaveEvent(Doc, false);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    // DOC is null or invalid. This occurs because the doc
                    // was closed. So we return doc closed and null as the
                    // document
                    AfterUiSaveEvent(null, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // if the document is still dirty
                // then we know an AutoSave happened
                try
                {
                    if (Doc.Saved == false)
                        AfterAutoSaveEvent(Doc, false); // fire autosave event
                    else
                        AfterSaveEvent(Doc, false); // fire regular save event
                }
                catch
                {
                    // DOC is closed
                    AfterSaveEvent(null, true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            // reset and exit thread
            oWord.Options.BackgroundSave = preserveBackgroundSave;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// WORD EVENT – Window Deactivate
    /// Fires just before we close the document and it
    /// is the last moment to get the filename
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Doc"></param>
    /// <param name="Wn"></param>
    void oWord_WindowDeactivate(Word.Document Doc, Word.Window Wn)
    {
        closedFilename = Doc.FullName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines if Word is busy  essentially that the File Save
    /// dialog is currently open
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="oApp"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool isBusy()
    {
        try
        {
            // if we try to access the application property while
            // Word has a dialog open, we will fail
            object o = oWord.ActiveDocument.Application;
            return false; // not busy
        }
        catch
        {
            // so, Word is busy and we return true
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how you set it up and attach to it’s events:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    WordSaveHandler wsh = null;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender,
                                    System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // attach the save handler
        wsh = new WordSaveHandler(Application);
        wsh.AfterAutoSaveEvent += new WordSaveHandler.AfterSaveDelegate(wsh_AfterAutoSaveEvent);
        wsh.AfterSaveEvent += new WordSaveHandler.AfterSaveDelegate(wsh_AfterSaveEvent);
        wsh.AfterUiSaveEvent += new WordSaveHandler.AfterSaveDelegate(wsh_AfterUiSaveEvent);
    }
    void wsh_AfterUiSaveEvent(Word.Document doc, bool isClosed)
    {
        if (!isClosed)
            MessageBox.Show("After SaveAs Event");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("After Close and SaveAs Event. The filname was: " + wsh.ClosedFilename);
    }

    void wsh_AfterSaveEvent(Word.Document doc, bool isClosed)
    {
        if (!isClosed)
            MessageBox.Show("After Save Event");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("After Close and Save Event. The filname was: " + wsh.ClosedFilename);
    }

    void wsh_AfterAutoSaveEvent(Word.Document doc, bool isClosed)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("After AutoSave Event");
    }

    // etc.

}
```