# VSTO Word post save event (with information of Cancel Save)

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, vsto

I know there is already a post with the same name as this but it provides a partial solution for the problem. The post is: [VSTO Word post save event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656564/vsto-word-post-save-event)

I'm using this class and it helped me a lot. However, when I make changes in the Word file and try to Close the application clicking in the option "Not Save" the event of save is raised.

How can I know if the user has clicked in the "Save" or "Not Save" buttom when trying to close the window? I've tried everything but I can't know this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing the same problem I found a solution. Before I open the file in Word I read all bytes and store in a class variable, for example, wordContent using

```
wordContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Then, every time that I save **without** closing the application (i.e clicking in the save buttom in Word) I update this variable wordContent.

So, when I close the application and the event AfterSave is fired with my variable isClosed == true, in this point I don't know if the user closed the application clicking in Save or Not Save. So, I read the bytes of the word File and compare with my wordContent. When the user has clicked in the "Save" option the contents will be different, and when the user has clicked in the "Not Save" options the contents will be equal.

So, whatever it needs to be done it'll be in the comparison of this two byte arrays.

Remembering that I'm using the WordSaveHandler provided by the post that I pointed in the question above, this class can handle if the users save by clicking in the Save Buttom or by closing the application.

Answer (score 0):

A quick test in VBA makes me believe this approach would be promising. `DocumentBeforeClose` is triggered before `DocumentBeforeSave`.

Declare a class-level field (`saveStatus` in the below code snippet).

In `DocumentBeforeClose` set it to "False" on the assumption the user won't save. If the user *does* save, set the value to True in `DocumentBeforeSave`. If you need to do something with the document when it's saved, put that code in this event, as well.

```
Private saveStatus as Boolean

Private Sub app_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
    saveStatus = False
    Debug.Print saveStatus
End Sub

Private Sub app_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    saveStatus = True
    Debug.Print saveStatus
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Cindy  , the problem is that when the users closes the application and the three options appears (Save, Not Save and Cancel) even when the option "Not Save" is clicked the event app_DocumentBeforeSave is fired, as it is when the "Save" option is clicked.

Comment: did you use the WordSaveHandler provided by the post that I pointed in the question?