# vsto excel add-in for 2007 save event

Tags: excel, events, save, vsto

How to get the save event on **excel add-in for 2007** project?
i know how to get the workbookBeforeSave event as below:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.WorkbookBeforeSave += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeSaveEventHandler(Application_WorkbookBeforeSave);
        }
```

but i want to get the afterSave Event.
i know excel add-in for 2010 provides the **WorkbookAfterSave**  event handler, but not for excel 2007.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTO Word post save event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36656564/vsto-word-post-save-event)

Comment: i saw this post, but did not know how to duplicate it. Because the possible propertis are different between Word.Application and Excel.Application. i can't find the property 
 such as "Word.Application.Options.BackgroundSave" at Excel。

Comment: Can you provide some code solution? thanks very much.

Comment: Sounds like it's not a valid solution for Excel 2007 then.

Comment: According to [the msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.aftersave.aspx), this event does not exist for Excel 2007, so you have to find a workaround